# how to convert c# to vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, converters

I would you convert this from C# code in vb.net

```
static List<UserDetail> ConnectedUsers = new List<UserDetail>();

if (ConnectedUsers.Count(x => x.ConnectionId == id) == 0){
    //do somthing 
}
```

I tried to convert with the website

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

and I've got this code,

```vb
If ConnectedUsers.Count(Function(x) x.ConnectionId = id) = 0 Then
    'do something
end if
```

but doesnt work visual studio tells me (error on this part 'ConnectedUsers.Count')
"'Public ReadOnly property count as integer' Has no parameters and its return value cannot be indexed. "

Thank you in advance for your help

**Edit 1**
I put it the declaration

```vb
Shared ConnectedUsers As New List(Of UserDetail)()
```

and in another class in the same namespace I have got this

```vb
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web

Namespace SignalRChat.Common
    Public Class UserDetail
        Public Property ConnectionId() As String
            Get
                Return m_ConnectionId
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                m_ConnectionId = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_ConnectionId As String
        Public Property UserName() As String
            Get
                Return m_UserName
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                m_UserName = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_UserName As String
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: And how do you have translated the declaration?

Comment: For reference: the syntax of lambda in VB.NET: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx

Comment: You missed the static List<UserDetail> ... conversion => Shared ConnectedUsers As New List(Of UserDetail)()

Comment: Side-note: you should use `!ConnectedUsers.Any(x => x.ConnectionId == id)` anyway instead of counting all. VB.NET: `Not ConnectedUsers.Any(Function(x) x.ConnectionId = id)`

Comment: Are you missing System.Linq from your list of imports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also try with

```
If ConnectedUsers.Where(Function(x) x.ConnectionId = id).Count = 0 Then
    Console.WriteLine("bingo")
end if
```

Or force your ConnectedUsers list to an IEnumerable and call the correct Count method

```
if ConnectedUsers.AsEnumerable().Count(Function(x) x.ConnectionId = id) Then
    Console.WriteLine("bingo")
end if
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```vb
Shared ConnectedUsers As New List(Of UserDetail)()
If ConnectedUsers.Count(Function(x) x.ConnectionId = id) = 0 Then
End If
```

I recommend using http://converter.telerik.com/ for converting c# to vb or vice versa.

But remember, that convert the code line by line, other wise, it will throw error.

Comment: I also have had better c#/vb translations with telerik than some of the other alternatives.

Comment: @Amit, thank you yes that is exactly what I have and the compiler is giving me the error that you can read in the post. I have to add that the declaration is outside the sub containing the if statement.